# How to avoid creation of EFI system partition during installation?

Tags: 12.04, uefi

I am installing Ubuntu 12.04. After creating partition it prompts for a partition for EFI. I do not want any such partition and have old MBR thing. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you are booting the installation [media in MBR mode, not UEFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_Ubuntu_DVD_in_EFI_mode). You might want to check the settings of your firmware setup screen (formerly called BIOS setup screen).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to **use a 32bit Ubuntu install media.**
As it technically cannot boot in UEFI mode, it will install Ubuntu in Legacy (MBR) mode for sure.

**If you really want to install a 64bit version,** then you need to [disable UEFI in your BIOS (UEFI firmware)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Set_up_the_BIOS_in_EFI_or_Legacy_mode) even before starting your Ubuntu disk. Depending on your firmware, this is not always easy/possible.